# JAVA: calculate the average between two or more arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have two double array like this:

```
 double[] a1={1.0,0.25,0.64,0.21};
 double[] a2={0.57,0.24,0.22,0.91};
```

How do I get another array docuble that would be the average between these two arrays?

THis code:

```
  public double average(double[] data) {  
    double sum = 0;

    while(int i=0; i < data.length; i++) 

    sum = sum + data[i]; 
    double average = sum / data.length;; 

    System.out.println("Average value of array element is " " + average);
}
```

Calculate the average of all the elements of an array, but I want to get another array that would represent the average of two or more arrays inserted into input!

Comment: Write down the forumula, ignoring any Java syntax. Just the mathematical formula. Now start applying it in a Java expression, then we can get the statement and block built. If you hit barriers post the specific code here and we'll help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will solve your problem:

```
public static double[] averages(double[]... input) {

    double[] result = new double[input.length];

    for(int i = 0; i< result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = Arrays.stream(input[i]).average().getAsDouble();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The code uses the [VarArgs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), so allows you to call it with various arguments.

`double[] avgs = averages(a1,a2);`

will result with array that has two doubles, each being an avg of items in array.

It uses Java 8 piece but it can be replaced by the code that calculate avg from single array.

---

In case of your code you have an issues.

Java do not know instruction like this

`while(int i=0; i < data.length; i++)`

it should be replaced with `for`

`for(int i=0; i < data.length; i++)`

Comment: This method Arrays.stream is not recognized, how can I do? My java version is:                                                             java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Update to java 8 or write simple method that calculate the avg form dobule array.